# Prove if $\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1+a_{n})$ converges, then $a_{n}$ approaches $0$. - Question on origin of idea

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation

A question I encountered in *Spivak's Calculus - Ch 23 - 25 (a)* asked:

Prove if $\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1+a_{n})$ converges, then $a_{n}$ approaches $0$. To begin I'll start off with the definition I was given:

> Let $b_n\neq0$. We say that the infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ *converges* if the sequence $p_n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n b_i$ converges, and also $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}p_n\neq 0$.

I worked on it for a bit, but wasn't able to get anywhere fruitful. Then I saw the solution:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P_{n}}{P_{n-1}} =  \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty}P_{n}}{\lim_{n \to \infty}P_{n-1}} = \frac{l}{l} = 1$$

Which is quite smooth. I would not have thought of looking at the quotient of the sequence terms. So my question is what type of question should I be asking myself in this scenario to look at an object like this?  What I mean is the following, if we were in my mind for a moment: "So I have these partial products, what can I do to these partial products to arrive at $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = 0$?"

It is here where I don't see how thinking of looking at the quotient would have been something to do. I know I'll probably get the "practice and experience" line. But beyond that, I should be asking the right sort of question to pull this tool from my toolbox.

Comment: You want to deduce an information about $a_n$ from an information about $P_n$, thus you have to find a relation between $a_n$ and $P_n$. For all $n$, you get $P_n$ by multiplying $P_{n-1}$ by $(1+a_n)$, that is to say $P_n=(1+a_n)P_{n-1}$. This is exactly the same idea as in the exercise : "if $\sum a_n$ converges then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n=0$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the solution is very elegant. It uses the fact that no $1  + a_k$ can be $= 0$ because otherwise $p_n = 0$ for $n \ge n_0$ which would prevent to form quotients $p_n/p_{n-1}$ for $n > n_0$. Note that if some $1 + a_k = 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n = 0$.

My first idea was to take logarithms. As we know, no $1 +a_k$ can be $= 0$. It is also impossible that infinitely many $ 1 + a_k < 0$ because then the sequence $(p_n)$ would have infinitely many positive terms and infinitely many negative terms (in which case the convergence of $(p_n)$ would imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n = 0$). Thus we may assume w.l.o.g. that all $1 + a_k > 0$. Then $p = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n > 0$ and
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln (1 + a_k) = \ln p_n \to \ln p ,$$
i.e.
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln (1 + a_k) = \ln p .$$
But this implies $\lim_{k \to \infty} \ln (1 + a_k) = 0$, thus $\lim_{k \to \infty} (1 + a_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} e^{\ln (1 + a_k)} = e^0 = 1$.

Comment: This was nice too.....I like this because this uses concepts that I've studied from start to finish. I really like the touch of the implication $\lim_{k \to \infty} \ln (1 + a_k) = 0$. It is one of those subtle conditions of convergent series that I did but kind of put it in the back of my mind thinking "cool condition, but I'll never have to use it."......and lo and behold how useful it became.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking would be if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_1^n b_k = L$ (for $b_k = 1+a_k)$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ so that for all $n > N$ then $|\prod_1^n b_k - L|<\epsilon$.  But the only thing $\prod_1^m b_k$ and $\prod_1^n a_k$ (for $m,n > N$) have in common about size so that $|\prod_1^n b_k-L| < \epsilon$ and $|\prod_1^m b_k - L|< \epsilon$, is that one is the product of more terms.  That means mean multiplying $\prod_1^n b_k$ but $b_{k-1}$ can't radically skew the result $|\prod_1^mb_k - L|< \epsilon$ and $|(\prod_1^mb_k)b_{m+1} - L|$ *also* $< \epsilon$ we can't have $b_{k+1}$ being significantly bigger or smaller than $1$.

And that's basically it. If $|\prod^m b_k - L| < \epsilon$ and $|\prod^{m+1} - L|< \epsilon$ solving for $b_{m+1}$ in terms of $\prod^m b_k$.....  the path becomes clear.

....

Note, the is *entirely* equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \implies a_k \to 0$.  And if we take $\log{\prod (b_k)} = \sum \log b_k$ and $b_k\to 1\implies \log b_k \to 0$, we can see why.